# Что нужно добавить, чтобы считалось кол-во проданных мест?

Tags: java

В кинозале 70 мест, нужно при каждой продаже считать сколько осталось билетов, чтобы по истечении 70 билетов появилось сообщение, что все билеты распроданы.
Так вот, подскажите, что изменить и-или что добавить в код, чтобы реализовать эту функцию.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kino {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Сколько Вам лет?");
        int alt = scn.nextInt();

        if (alt <= 5) {
            System.out.println("Цена билета: бесплатно");
        } 
        else if (alt >= 5 && alt <= 12) {
            System.out.println("Цена билета: 5р.");
        }
        else if (alt >= 13) {
            System.out.println("Цена билета: 10р.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Коли вы хотите, чтобы задачу решили за вас, то вам следует обратиться на биржу фрилансеров. Stack Overflow - это ресурс для людей, которые хотят научиться решать задачи самостоятельно. А в вашем коде нет ни единого намека на то, что вы пытались реализовать данный функционал.

Comment: нужно добавить общее количество билетов (70), бесконечный цикл, который заканчивается когда билетов больше нет и на каждой итерации уменьшать счетчик (70) до нуля

Comment: Она почти решена, я не  могу понять, как перебрать кол-во билетов, которые остались. Всего-то.

Comment: @Макс у вас тут, кстати не видно ничего из отсчета билетов)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kino {

    static int countOfTickets = 70;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (countOfTickets > 0) {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Сколько Вам лет?");
            int alt = scn.nextInt();
            countOfTickets--;
            if (alt <= 5) {
                System.out.println("Цена билета: бесплатно");
            }
            else if (alt >= 5 && alt <= 12) {
                System.out.println("Цена билета: 5р.");
            }
            else if (alt >= 13) {
                System.out.println("Цена билета: 10р.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Все билеты распроданы!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае как-то так:

```
int tickets = 3;

Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    if (tickets == 0) {
        System.out.println("Все билеты проданы!");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Сколько Вам лет?");
    int alt = scn.nextInt();

    if (alt <= 5) {
        System.out.println("Цена билета: бесплатно");
    } else if (alt >= 5 && alt <= 12) {
        System.out.println("Цена билета: 5р.");
    } else if (alt >= 13) {
        System.out.println("Цена билета: 10р.");
    }

    tickets--;
}
```

Есть счетчик билетов (в данном случае их 3 штуки), бесконечный цикл, который заканчивается когда билетов больше нет (`if (tickets == 0)`) и на каждой итерации уменьшать счетчик.